# Angular - Module Federation: How can I make static files (assets/i18n) available to the remote(MFE) when it is used inside a shell

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-5, webpack-module-federation

We have an application that consists of several angular projects (MFE's) loaded inside a single shell. All of this is achieved using [this plugin](https://github.com/angular-architects/module-federation-plugin).
Everything works well, but now we need to add i18n, but it's unpractical to have all the strings defined in the shell like this:

[image]

Since the package we use for i18n, [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core), supports loading translation from feature modules, we're looking for a way that let us define them inside the same folder of the feature module so that they would be also available when they're loaded inside the shell.

So far the only way I've found to share the translations defined in each remote is the following:

1. Define our i18n json files inside the feature module that is exposed (**requests**) via module federation

[image]

2. Implement a custom translation loader and inside import every json file. That way those files will be part the code being exported

```html
import { TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import en from '../assets/i18n/en.json';
import es from '../assets/i18n/es.json';


export class CustomTranslationLoader implements TranslateLoader  {
  languages: any = {
    en,
    es
  }
  constructor() {}

  getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any> {
      return of(this.languages[lang]);
  }
}
```

3. Finally use the previously defined custom translation loader inside the feature module

```html
 @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        ...
      ],
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        TranslateModule.forChild({
          defaultLanguage: 'es',
          loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useClass: CustomTranslationLoader,
          },
          isolate: true
        }),
        RequestsRoutingModule,
      ]
    })
    export class RequestsModule
```

This works, but I don't like the idea of having to manually import every single translation file like I do in step 2.
I'd like to find a way to dynamically load the require file using the **http client**. Something like this:

```
export class CustomTranslationLoader implements TranslateLoader  {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any> {
      return this.http.get('../assets/i18n' + lang + '.json');
  }
}
```

Unfortunately this is not possible since only static files inside assets are served.

I also tried adding my new folder to the angular.json file like this, but those files are available during development:

[image]

Do you know how can I achieve what I describe above or perhaps a better way of exposing the translations (en.json, es.json, etc)  each remote defines so that the shell can add them to its own translations?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @eddy, did you find a solution for this issue because we have the same issue, In our case what we did we define the translation in both host and remote but I believe this is not the best practice, so if you solved this issue could you please share with us your solution.
Thanks,

Comment: Yep. Use a environment variable (environmet.ts) for this with absolute routing and then with azure devops variables we changed the `http://locahost:3000/assets` to `https://whateveryourdomain.com/assets`. The static files are still there you just need to tell the shell where exactly.

Comment: Could you please explain more and share your solution if you don't mind, because i didn't got your point

Comment: My bad. My last comment was regarding another question. In this particular case I just did what I showed in my question. Each feature module defines its own i18n files and https://github.com/ngx-translate/core does the rest for you. You don't have to repeat the same translations on the shell, they will be lazy-loaded when you feature module is loaded.

Comment: I am a same problem. Do you have a solution

Comment: Hi @eddy how do you sync language between shell and remotes?